# single page site with subpages

Tags: loop, pages, single

i want to make a single page site which has subpages with following structure

about us
team
-member1
-member2
contact

and i want the output to be like

```
<div class="about-us">
team content
</div>
<div class="team">
team content
    <div class="subpages">
         <div class="member1">
         member1 content
         </div>
         <div class="member12">
         member2 content
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="contact">
team content
</div>
```

and this is my loop so far

```
<?php query_posts(array('post_type'=>page, 'orderby'=>menu_order, 'post_parent' => $thePostID)); ?>

        <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

             <?php if ( 0 == $post->post_parent ) { ?>
             <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
             <?php } else { ?>
                 <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
             <?php } ?>
             <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
             <?php the_content(); ?>
        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>
```

thanks for helping, helmut

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it's very simple, but a bit static.
You can make a new `front-page.php` with the structure you mentioned. Then first make some pages (i.e.: About us, Members 1, Contact etc.) in your `wp-admin`. And use the [get_page() function](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page) to call different page [using their individual ID] into different zone.

Am I right?

Comment: i did not think about that possibility ... you mean a loop for each page with subpage using the spezific id on one page?

Comment: I din't try this before. So, please try and let me know whether it works or not. Look at a simple `page.php` page [HERE](http://themeshaper.com/2012/11/06/the-wordpress-theme-search-template-and-page-template/) which is responsible for showing `Pages` (NOT `Posts`). There is no loop or something, just a simple `the_post();` function to call the post. Use the simple way I mentioned above to get a specific page content using its ID and then echo the page content using `the_post()` and `the_content()`. If it works, then improvise it in your way. :)

Comment: Sorry, the `page.php` code is [HERE](http://themeshaper.com/2009/07/02/wordpress-theme-search-page-template-tutorial/). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Now it is tested. I created **PAGE** (not POST) in admin panel and then used the page's ID here in a `front-page.php` file (it will override the `index.php`, but won't create any problem):

```php
        <div class="about-us">
        <?php
       // VERY SIMPLE LOGIC
           $page_data = get_page(9); // page_id will be your Team page's ID (mine was 9)
           echo $page_data->post_content; // simply get the content of the page (without formatting)
        ?>
       </div> <!-- .about-us -->

       <div class="team">
            <?php
            // EXACT IMPLEMENTATION
                $page_data = get_page( 6 ); // page_id will be your Team page's ID (mine was 6)
                echo '<h3>'. $page_data->post_title .'</h3>';       // to echo the page title       
                echo apply_filters('the_content', $page_data->post_content); // this filter will allow formatting from your page
            ?>

            <div class="subpages">
                <div class="member1">
                    <?php
                    // JUST SEE WHAT YOU GOT
                        $page_data = get_page( 7 ); // page_id will be your Team page's ID (mine was 7)
                        var_dump( $page_data ); // var_dump will show you all the things what get_page() has brought to you.
                    ?>
                </div> <!-- .member1 -->
                <div class="member2">
                    Member2 content
                </div> <!-- .member2 -->
            </div> <!-- .subpages -->

       </div> <!-- .team -->

       <div class="contact">
            Contact page content
       </div> <!-- .contact -->
```

I commented inline. The whole thing is tested as per the code given in [Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_page). I've already shared that with you. with `var_dump()` see what it takes for you and improvise it whatever you like. (Thanks to Asadul Islam Sohag for assisting me)

Yap! Code is Poetry!

Comment: thats exact what i was looking for, thanks ... i try to make a more dynamic version of it, if it works, i let you know and post the code.